# c# graphics animation with timer tick flickering

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am trying to make an animation in WinForms, C#. I have a timer, and for each tick, I move a circle around a panel on a form. It works, but the display is not smooth, it seems to flicker. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

code generated for form:

```cs
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // panel1
    // 
    this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
    this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(435, 313);
    this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);
    // 
    // timer1
    // 
    this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    // 
    // frmBoxerTest
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(459, 337);
    this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
    this.Name = "frmBoxerTest";
    this.Text = "frmBoxerTest";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmBoxerTest_Load);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion

private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
```

own code for animation:

```cs
public partial class frmBoxerTest : Form
{
    float myLeft = 100F;
    float myTop = 100F;
    float horDirection = 10F;
    float verDirection = 8F;

    public frmBoxerTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmBoxerTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        StartShowing();
    }

    private void StartShowing()
    {

        timer1.Interval = 100;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //same result if I do the graphics here.
        //e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        //e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, myLeft, myTop, 50F, 50F);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (panel1.Width <= myLeft + 50F || myLeft <= -1)
        {
            horDirection = horDirection * -1;   //reverse horizontal direciton
        }
        myLeft += horDirection;

        if (panel1.Height <= myTop + 50F || myTop <= -1)
        {
            verDirection = verDirection * -1;   //reverse vertical direciton
        }
        myTop += verDirection;

        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, myLeft, myTop, 50F, 50F);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a PictureBox instead of a Panel and use its Paint event handler **only**. -- A PictureBox is double-buffered by default, a Panel is not. Setting double-buffering on the parent Form doesn't help much.

Comment: and, i think use reduce the timer interval and move step(`horDirection & verDirection`) might be helpful.

Comment: -Can you reduce the image interval to 20 ( to have 50 frames )./
-You dont need a Panel to draw, you can draw directly on the form./
-you can increase the buffer and create the shape inside  : 
        BufferedGraphicsContext context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        context.MaximumBuffer = new Size( this.Width + 1, this.Height + 1 );
        bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate( this.CreateGraphics(),
        new Rectangle( 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height) );

Comment: would it help to add the bufferGraphics to the answer below? Where would I add that, in the timer or in the Paint event?

Comment: Since your Control is double-buffered now, you're [already using a BufferedGraphics object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,13651) -- Manual handling of a BufferedGraphics object is useful if you draw stuff off screen, then replace the current buffer with the cached one when needed. A double-buffered Control already handles this in normal conditions.

Comment: oh wow, learning a lot here, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jimi - that seemed to have been exactly the problem.
I changed it to a PictureBox and it works smoothly

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, myLeft, myTop, 50F, 50F);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBox1.Width <= myLeft + 50F || myLeft <= -1)
            {
                horDirection = horDirection * -1;   //reverse horizontal direciton
            }
            myLeft += horDirection;

            if (pictureBox1.Height <= myTop + 50F || myTop <= -1)
            {
                verDirection = verDirection * -1;   //reverse vertical direciton
            }
            myTop += verDirection;

            //Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            //g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            //g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            //g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, myLeft, myTop, 50F, 50F);

            //pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

        }
```